# Why does not work for default shipping method? For WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to default DHL. But it doesn't work, why is that? In WooCommerce from WordPress.

You can see here: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glNXs.png). Way - `functions.php`

```
function reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {

    if ( ! empty( $method ) ) {
        return $method;
    }        

    $method = 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate9';

    return $method;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter has been updated you should try this. 
I've tested it and it works for me.

Also, the default shipping is stored in your session so if you want to test it you can try from a new browser or log out and log back in.

```
 function prefix_reset_default_shipping_method( $default, $package, $chosen_method ) {

        if( $default !== 'flat_rate:9')
            $default = 'flat_rate:9';

        return $default;

    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'prefix_reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {
    $default_method = 'wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping:FEDEX_GROUND'; //provide here the service name which will selected default
    if( array_key_exists($method, $available_methods ) )
        return $default_method;
    else
        return $method;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 2);
```

Add this to your theme's functions.php changing the $default_method var.

source: https://www.xadapter.com/set-default-shipping-method-woocommerce/